# How to link many objects to a singular object in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am making an android application that uses Parse.com as its server backend.I want to enable users to post comments to poems uploaded but am stuck on how to link many comments to a particular poem Object.Does anyone have an idea of how to do that?Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You create the comment as an instance of class=comment that is separate from the Poem instance, saving the object ID that parse returns on 'insert comment'.

Then, as a child of Poem object, you have 'comments' attribute under which you insert ArrayType pointer to the ID returned by the previous insert to the comment class.

```
   '{"comments":{"__op":"Add","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer",
    "className":"Comment","objectId":"$returnValueOfCommentInsert"}]}}'
```

The pointer type entity is added (ptrToComment) is added to an array of pointers sitting in 'comments' entity inside Poem object.

This assumes use of Rest API.

Comment: am using android with parse sdk

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation is a good start. How about the section on [Andriod Relational Data](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers)?